# Include FactoryGirl methods inside an RSpec context?

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

How do I go about including the FactoryGirl methods, like `create` directly inside a context?

For example, when I am outside a context, this will work

```
role_all = create(:role, name: 'all')
```

Because in my `spec_helper.rb` I have the following,

```
config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
```

But when I am inside a context, I need to include `FactoryGirl.` before a method call, like so,

```
context 'has role all' do
  role_all = FactoryGirl.create(:role, name: `all`)
  subject(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, roles: [ role_all ]) }
  # test assumptions on user 
end
```

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Why would you like to call it outside of any example?

Comment: Because the context is setting up data to be used by each test. Editing to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be setting up data inside the context - it is only being read once when rspec is collecting all the examples and won't be executed again. If it currently works it is only because you are not resetting your db for every test which might lead to some issues. Instead use `before` hooks:

```
context 'has role all' do
  before(:each) { @role_all = create(:role, name: `all`) }
end
```

Also note that `subject` block is not executed when it is declared - it will be executed every time you call subject in your test. Since ruby procs carry the context they have been created at, `role_all` declared in your code won't raise any exception. However your `subject` will return different object each time you call it and it might make your test missed.

TL;DR:

Context is not to set data for tests - it is to set the functions which will be run before or after each test.

Comment: Wow, that explains some of test db issues I was having before, thanks!